# Getting Ping Fluctuation

Tags: ping

i have two PC connected using 2 switches. (i.e. 1st PC+-----+Switch 1+----+Switch 2+----+2nd PC).

```
Ip- Adreess of 1st PC : 192.168.100.1
Ip- Adreess of 2nd PC : 192.168.100.51
```

Note- I have connected two switches using "straight cable".

When i ping on 1st PC, I m not getting continues reply. Result as shown below:

```
Reply from 192.168.100.51: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 192.168.100.51: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 192.168.100.51: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 192.168.100.51: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Request timed out.
Reply from 192.168.100.51: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 192.168.100.51: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Reply from 192.168.100.51: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 192.168.100.51: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Request timed out.
```

---

What could be the possible reasons for that?

Answer (score 0):

(Not really a SO question)

If it is a HW fail then:

```
Test connect PC1 - cross-cable - PC2
Test connect PC1 - Switch 1 - PC2
Test connect PC1 - Switch 2 - PC2
Use new cables
```

Other reason network saturation (too much traffic).

Comment: I have checked the cable connections and they are working pretty good. As per your response it seems like the network is congested. Moreover I realised that, a reason for congestion can be the hardware configuration of proxy server. (That is very low in fact). Any other possible reasons?